# Visualizing two sets of data on one map in D3: Is there a way to map two datasets to a range -1 to 1?

Tags: csv, d3.js, data-visualization, data-cleaning

I have two csv files containing countries and values that correspond to each country.
The data from CSV 1 denotes the number of times a country *has been attacked* on their own soil.
The data from CSV 2 denotes the number of times a country *has attacked* another country abroad.
There is overlap between the two sets of data and I intend to demonstrate values from both data sets in one grey scale range to be shown on a choropleth map.

I have some (obviously) phony data below to demonstrate what I'm working with.

```
TARGET.csv
country, code, value
Iran, IRN, 5
Russia, RUS, 4
United States, USA, 0
Egypt, EGY, 2
Spain, ESP, 1
```

```
ATTACKER.csv
country, code, value
Iran, IRN, 3
Russia, RUS, 9
United States, USA, 4
Egypt, EGY, 0
Spain, ESP, 0
```

There are more targets than attackers.
I want to ensure that I represent the data accurately, but do not know how I would create a normalized range of values between -1 and 1.
It is my understanding that displaying the data in this way would accurately represent the reality best, but I feel like I may be wrong.

In summation:

1) Am I thinking about this problem properly? Is this even the right way to think about displaying the data?

2) What is the proper language used to describe my question?
I am usually able to figure these things out but I'm stumped with dead-end search queries.

3) How do I make sure that my range is normalized. Notice that USA above appears as the only attacker who has never been a target, Would that make the USA the nearest value to +1, despite Russia's larger number of attacks?

I would appreciate whatever input you all can offer.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale). Use `scale.range([-1, 1])` to define the desired target output, and `scale.domain()` with min and max values from the source data to define the input set.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, I will look into that. Follow up question - would leaving the two data sets in tact and handling them separately within my D3 project be a better course of action than trying to finesse the data sets into a single range /and then/ mapping it?

Comment: @NYezhov the answer of transforming/consolidating the data is more logistical or stylistic than a technical.  Will your data sets derive from different sources, will they change? If so, segregation may be more manageable.  d3 can certainly handle that by layering multiple components in the same viz.  Consolidation may be easier or more elegant, or shorter, or more extensible, e.g., if one or both of your models will change, a single function to transform may be more maintainable (or not :)